# The button background is auto changed?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-button

My app has 2 activities:

- MainActivity has a button to start SubActivity, this button isn't set transparent.
- SubActivity has a button that is transparent by setAlpha().

My problem is sometimes, when I back to MainActivity from SubActivity by pressing back button, a button of MainActivity becomes transparent same as button of SubActivity. This problem occurs frequently if I exit the app and open it again.

I also try to set the alpha 255 for button1 and 120 for button2 in the onResume() of each activity but it doesn't work. Sometimes button1 becomes transparent, sometimes button2 is not transparent.

I upload MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.buttondemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private Button button1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

SubActivity.java:

```
package com.example.buttondemo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Button;

public class SubActivity extends Activity {

    private Button button2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sub);

        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.getBackground().setAlpha(120);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sub, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

\res\values\strings.xml:

```
<string name="app_name">ButtonDemo</string>
<string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
<string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
<string name="title_activity_sub">SubActivity</string>
<string name="button1_label">button1</string>
<string name="button2_label">button2</string>
```

\res\layout\activity_main.xml;

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button1_label"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

\res\layout\activity_sub.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".SubActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button2_label"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

\res\drawable\button_selector.xml:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_button" /> <!-- pressed -->
    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/pressed_button" /> <!-- focused -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/default_button" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can cover this issues, It is because 2 buttons refer to same drawable resources (pressed_button.png and default_button.png). When I set transparent for button2 in the source code, seem that it also effects its drawable resource. Then, button1 also refer to this resource, it causes the unstable background.

I try to remove source code that set the background for buttons, and this problem never occurs. So I think the condition of this problem is:
- Set the background in same drawable file for buttons dynamically in source code (.java), set transparent for one of them.

So that, I make a copy for drawable resource named that pressed_button1.png and default_button1.png for button2 from the original ones (pressed_button.png, default_button.png). It means now the button1 refer to original drawable and button2 refer to the new ones. And the result is very strange, IT CAN WORK WELL.

I also test on Android 4.2, beside the way that I make a copy for drawable resource, I can set transparent in .xml by android:alpha, It also works well.

Hope this will help! :)